# Center text next to image in dynamically created div. jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

At the moment, the text is aligned with the top of the image. Is there any way for me to pad the text down so it is aligned with the center of the image?

Any padding I add to ui-title moves the entire div.

Or would I have to restructure the jQuery to achieve this?

```
           pageDiv.append(
                $('<div>').addClass('ui-title').text('hello').append(
                    $('<img class="confirm" src="image.png" alt="" height="30" width="30"></img>')
                )
            )
```

Comment: Don't need to add `</img>`...

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE with your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `</img>`. `img` tags can be self closing so you can change your declaration to `<img class="confirm" src="image.png" alt="" height="30" width="30" />`.

You can use `vertical-align: middle;` but you'll need to make sure the `div` containing your text is set to be an inline element to vertically align it which can be done using `display: inline;`. You can also use `display: inline-block;` with `vertical-align` which has a mix of properties between `inline` and `block` elements as the name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, not perfect but it works. Just added this CSS.

```
    .ui-title img{
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: If you add a fiddle with your code, people can help you come up with a better solution.  Nobody would recommend doing it this way.